# почему python не распознаёт русский язык при чтении текстового файла?

Tags: python

есть текстовый файл: test2.txt, а в нём строка: "Привет, я тестовый файл!".
проблема в том, что этот код выдаёт странные символы, вместо русского текста:

```
ff = open('test2.txt','r')
print(ff.read())
ff.close()
```

при записи в текстовый файл цифр или английских букв всё выводит нормально.

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа

Comment: Я думаю, что если при открытии файла дописать encoding="utf-8", то это решит вашу проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
ff = open('test2.txt','r', enconding="<YOUR_FILE_ENCODING_GOES_HERE>")
print(ff.read())
ff.close()
```

Если вы скинули в те "странные символы", я б угадал че за кодировка, а так думаю, что `cp1251`.

*Good luck!*

Comment: РџСЂРёРІРµС‚,СЌС‚Рѕ С‚РµСЃС‚РѕРІС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р»! вот